# Marginal Effect in a Gamma GLM with Quadratic Terms

Tags: regression, gamma-distribution, marginal-effect

I am building a gamma GLM regression model with a log link function. The model I fit is below:

[image: log(y) = 6.04 + 0.00016(x) - 0.0000000027(x)^{2} + 0.00013(z)]

I understand that I can calculate the marginal effect of x on log(y) by taking the derivative with respect to x. How can I calculate the marginal effect of x on y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{dy}{dx} & = \frac{dy}{d\log y} \frac{d\log y}{dx} \\
& = \left(\frac{d\log y}{dy}\right)^{-1} \frac{d\log y}{dx} \\
& = y \cdot \frac{d\log y}{dx}
\end{split}
$$
In practice this means that the marginal effect of $x$ on $y$ *depends on the value of $y$, so you'd have to pick reference values of $x$ and $z$ (typically the mean values) to do the calculation.

Alternatively, you can frame the marginal effect on a log-response as a *proportional* change. If you compute the marginal effect of $x$ on $\log y$ and exponentiate it, you can frame it as a proportional effect (e.g. "a one-unit change in $x$ is associated with a ()-fold change in $y$")

Comment: Thank you very much for writing out this explanation for me!

Is it possible to explain why exponentiating the marginal effect of x on log y gives you the proportional effect on y? Also, in my case, am I right that this proportionate effect on y would be 
[e^{0.00016- 0.0000000052x}](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?e^{0.00016-&space;0.0000000052x})